# How I add retina images to my app? Do I just add like "@2x"?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, retina-display

I Have an app full of images, but when you run it on retina displays it gets pixelized, I have the same images with double resolution, but I don't know ho to add them to my project...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes just add "@2x" to the name of your image files.

So if you have an image "someimage.png" in low resolution, name the high resolution version of this image "someimage@2x.png".

Then you have nothing to do in your code, as when you write `[UIImage imageNamed:@"someimage"]` or `[UIImage imageNamed:@"someimage.png"]` the runtime will load the right image "someimage.png" or "someimage@2x.png" depending on the resolution of the iPhone the user is running your app on.

---

For more information, **read the [Resource Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/SupportingHiResScreensInViews/SupportingHiResScreensInViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH15) in Apple Documentation**, especially the paragraph "**Updating Your Image Resource Files**" where everything is explained in details.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as in your title. Add the image to your project with the same name as your original image but with "@2x". For example if you have "example.png" you add the retina image into your project with the name "example@2x.png" and Xcode will automatically use that image if it detects a retina display. No coding is needed.